# How to scrape time_zone from IPStack?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

**EDIT: I have solved the issue: the time_zone module requires a paid subscription**

The aim is to scrape the user's timezone (from IP address) through IPStack.

I am able to scrape the data contained in the 'main' section. That is, those that don't require "specify response fields". However, the remainder of the data, such as that contained within 'time_zone', I am having trouble scraping it.

I am quite new to scraping, so perhaps I am making an obvious error.

The documentation can be found here: https://ipstack.com/documentation.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

baseurl = """
http://api.ipstack.com/155.42.107.7
?access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_CODE
&fields=time_zone
"""
f = urlopen(baseurl)
json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
timezone_id = parsed_json['time_zone']['id']
f.close()
print(timezone_id)
```

> The output is: "KEYERROR: 'time_zone'"

Thank you, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: show us the output you are getting in parsed_json

Comment: This is no scrapping. This is calling an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the `time_zone` is now restricted to paid access keys.

[image]

I would suggest using [GeoTimeZone](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GeoTimeZone/) to map coordinates to a unix time zone and then [TimeZoneMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeZoneMapper/) to map to a .NET time zone.

Comment: Hello i plan to use it. But the free plan doesnt give me the precise coordinates. And I am willing to pay for it if someone tell it gives the exact coordinates. Can someone?

Comment: @SocratesTuas you cannot get exact coordinates from an IP address. Sometimes coordinates are acceptable, sometimes you get an ISP box in a town, sometimes you get the country's capital city... This is nothing like GPS.